# Code igniter email fail "SMTP error was encountered: 550 Unknown user"

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am using codeigniter email facility to send emails.

The list of people is an array of email addressess that are emailed in the organisation. However some changes often take place and some emails get deactiavted and it appears that if the array of people that are being emailed contain at least a single entry that is fasle (person no longer exists) the whole email fails to send and gives the following error:

```
from: 250 OK

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 250 Accepted

to: 550 Unknown user

The following SMTP error was encountered: 550 Unknown user

quit: 221 closing connection

Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Is there a way to tell codeigniter to ignore the incorrect email addresses and send the email anyway to the rest of them?

Comment: Are you sending _one_ e-mail with _all_ those recipients specified as `To:` in one go? Send individual e-mails in a loop then instead …?

Comment: Yes they are sent all in one go as the array of emails is used to set the bcc field.

Comment: I don't think it's a CodeIgniter thing. That looks like log entries from the mail server itself which is out of CI's control.